# Attempting to optimize sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I have the following query that takes several seconds to run:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
   FROM [PTYCHRG] A, [AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP] B
  WHERE TRIM(A.CASE_ID) = TRIM(caseid)
    AND TRIM(B.casecode) = TRIM(casecd)
    AND (
            TRIM(A.ACTN_CD) = TRIM(B.ACTIONCODE)
            OR TRIM(A.INDICTED_ACTN_CD) = TRIM(B.ACTIONCODE)
            OR TRIM(A.AMENDED_ACTN_CD) = TRIM(B.ACTIONCODE)
        )
    AND LOWER(TRIM(B.DOMAIN)) = LOWER(TRIM(domain))
    AND [rownum] = 1;
```

I'm looking for a way/method to speed it up significantly as it is a part of a larger process.

I am basically looking to see if there is at least one record (I don't care what field I pull back, I just want to know if there is at least one record).

Any ideas on what I can do different to make it run faster?

Comment: Can you check whether you are missing any Indexes.

Comment: Show us the output of `DESCRIBE {your query}` please, so you and we can see some information about the indexes it uses.

Comment: it always helps if you write out joins

Comment: Whenever you apply functions like TRIM and LOWER to your fields, the query planner cannot use indexes. Check if those id fields really need trimming.

Comment: What is `rownum`?  It doesn't have a table alias and it looks suspicious.

Comment: Can you test this with [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181091.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

This is your query rewritten with proper `join` syntax, better table aliases, and fewer parentheses::

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
FROM PTYCHRG p JOIN
     AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP atc
     ON TRIM(p.CASE_ID) = TRIM(atc.caseid) AND
        TRIM(atc.casecode) = TRIM(p.casecd) AND
        TRIM(atc.ACTIONCODE) IN (TRIM(p.ACTN_CD), TRIM(p.INDICTED_ACTN_CD), TRIM(p.AMENDED_ACTN_CD)) AND
        LOWER(TRIM(atc.DOMAIN)) = LOWER(TRIM(p.domain)) AND
 WHERE rownum = 1;
```

None of these fix any problems.  Instead, they make it easier to higlight problems.  First, you are running functions on values.  This usually prevents SQL Server from using indexes, or even making more informed decisions about joins.  If spaces are really a problem, there are two solutions:  a functional index or fix the data.  I would go with fixing the data:

```
update PTYCHRG
    set Case_Id = TRIM(Case_id),
        ActionCode = TRIM(ActionCode),
        ACTN_CD = TRIM(ACTN_CD),
        INDICTED_ACTN_CD = TRIM(INDICTED_ACTN_CD),
        AMENDED_ACTN_CD = TRIM(AMENDED_ACTN_CD),
        domain = lower(trim(domain));

update AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP
    set caseid = trim(caseid),
        casecode = trim(casecode)
        ACTIONCODE = trim(ACTIONCODE),
        domain = lower(trim(domain));
```

Then the query becomes:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM PTYCHRG p JOIN
     AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP atc
     ON p.CASE_ID = atc.caseid AND
        atc.casecode = p.casecd AND
        atc.ACTIONCODE IN (p.ACTN_CD, p.INDICTED_ACTN_CD, p.AMENDED_ACTN_CD) AND
        atc.DOMAIN = p.domain AND
 WHERE rownum = 1;
```

And then I would recommend indexes.  You can try:

```
create index idx_AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP_4
    on AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP(caseid, casecode, domain, actioncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ryan

Can you see, whether the SQL gives same result as yours.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM    [PTYCHRG] A
JOIN    [AVAIL_ACTION_TYPE_CODES_TEMP] B
ON      TRIM(A.CASE_ID) = TRIM(caseid)
AND     ISNULL(TRIM(A.ACTN_CD),ISNULL(TRIM(A.INDICTED_ACTN_CD),TRIM(A.AMENDED_ACTN_CD))) = TRIM(B.ACTIONCODE)
WHERE   [rownum] = 1
```

If avoidable, remove `TRIM()` from the sql as well